# How to disable cache in Laravel 8 for localserver?

Tags: php, laravel, caching

How to disable cache in Laravel 8 for localserver? Its creating too much cache files. Its taking too much time to reflect changes.

Comment: Do you want to disable cache for views or ?

Comment: For view & routes.

Comment: Read that article [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-caching). If you didn't run `php artisan route:cache` it wouldn't cache your routes.

Comment: @FatimaMazhit Thanks. But it is still on local and I didn't run `php artisan route:cache`.

Comment: Is it definitely your routes/views cache and not your browser cache? Does the issue seem to go away (at least for one request) if you run `php artisan route:clear && php artisan view:clear`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To disable the cache you have to add the following to your config/cache.php file.

```
    'stores' => [
    //...
    'none' => [
        'driver' => 'null',
    ],
  ],
```

Now you have to change your CACHE_DRIVER value to none in your .env file and your cache is disabled.

Comment: I think the preferred way is to set CACHE_DRIVER=array in .env

Answer (score 10):

```
// .env file  

CACHE_DRIVER=array
```

*Suggested by [Taylor](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2501#issuecomment-26570693) himself.*

Then run `php artisan optimize:clear` to clear all cached files.

This will also disable everything that uses cache between requests e.g. RateLimiter

Answer (score 4):

In your .env file, set:

CACHE_DRIVER=array

Arrays are not persisted between requests.

Answer (score 2):

You can do multiple things like:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=none
```

```
CACHE_EXPIRE=-1
```

and a command to clear view cache:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: Note: You have to actually define the cache store first.

Comment: CACHE_EXPIRE is not present anywhere in Laravel 8's source. Where did you get that?